# Having some trouble with weather-js and args

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I have a command in my bot, called weather, it works fine, but i want to send an error message if the user writes it without any arguments.

It works if the arguments are not a place, but if you write it without any args, it doesnt reply anything

Here's the code (Updated with entire code)

```
      const Discord = require('discord.js');
const weather = require('weather-js');

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

    weather.find({search: args[0], degreeType: "C"}, function(err, result){
        if (err) message.channel.send(err);

        const noargs = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setDescription(`Input a valid location, please`)
        .setColor(0xfd5454)

        if(!result.length) {
            message.channel.send(noargs);
            return;
        }

        var current = result[0].current;
        var location = result[0].location;
```

It works if you write ",weather nonexistingcity" but if you write ",weather" without any args, it doesnt work.
PD: noargs is a discord embed, is declared but not included in this post.

Comment: How do you declare your arguments?

Comment: The code shown is too minimal to be complete .... [mcve]

Comment: do you want me to post full code?

Comment: No, only the relevant code.

Comment: ok, i posted relevant

Answer (score 1):

```
const weather = require('weather-js');

const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "weather",
    description: "Checks a weather forecast",

    async execute(client, message, cmd, args, Discord){

    weather.find({search: args.join(" "), degreeType: 'F'}, function (error, result){
        // 'C' can be changed to 'F' for farneheit results
        if(error) return message.channel.send(error);
        if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Please specify a location')

        if(result === undefined || result.length === 0) return message.channel.send('**Invalid** location');

        var current = result[0].current;
        var location = result[0].location;

        const weatherinfo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(`**${current.skytext}**`)
        .setAuthor(`Weather forecast for ${current.observationpoint}`)
        .setThumbnail(current.imageUrl)
        .setColor(0x111111)
        .addField('Timezone', `UTC${location.timezone}`, true)
        .addField('Degree Type', 'Celsius', true)
        .addField('Temperature', `${current.temperature}°`, true)
        .addField('Wind', current.winddisplay, true)
        .addField('Feels like', `${current.feelslike}°`, true)
        .addField('Humidity', `${current.humidity}%`, true)


        message.channel.send(weatherinfo)
        })        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if no args where provoided you can do :

```
if(args.length == 0) return message.channel.send('You need to provide a city');
```

Comment: Yeah, but weather-js is programmed to answer the user if he didnt provide args with a default message. I want to know how to change that message. Here's a screenshot. Blue is what i programmed. Red is what the author programmed to answer and i dont know how to change it https://www.dropbox.com/s/st9n4lki6ed7vih/InkedCaptura%20de%20pantalla%202019-04-22%2023.07.49_LI.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Yeah just do `if(args.length == 0) return message.channel.send(noargs)` before weather js. Obv also move the `const noargs =` that will check if somebody did `;weather` without any inout and send the embed

Answer (score 0):

> ...`weather-js` is programmed to answer the user if he didn't provide args with a default message. I want to know how to change that message.

If you *really* want to change this message instead of checking your arguments yourself like @PLASMA chicken has suggested, the message is located on line 31 of `weather-js/index.js`.